# How to fix flickering on hover replacing text

Tags: html, css

If mouse on text as hover flickering text.

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: black
}

.new {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.old:hover  {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility:hidden;
}
.new:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

<div class="old">Old</div>
<div class="new">New</div>
```

How i can show text New if mouse hover (without wrapper please)?
 [Code on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uxyz7ksq/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uxyz7ksq/7/

Comment: How i can fix hide "Old" if show and move mouse on text "New"? https://jsfiddle.net/uxyz7ksq/12/

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [content](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/pr_gen_content.asp) along with [:after](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/sel_after.asp) to replace text

```css
div {
    position: block;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: black
}

.old:after{
    content:'old';
}
.old:hover:after{
    content:'new';
}
```

```html
<div class="old"></div>
```

**Edited**
I think you have been asking that **old** must disappear on hover and **new** must stay forever even after hover effects.
This can be done by transition effects. This time I go for [Allan Jebaraj's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8547884/allan-jebaraj) answer using z-index and altering the opacity transition effects.

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: black
}

.new {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 9999s;
}

.old {
  z-index: 1;
  transition: opacity 9999s;
}

.old:hover {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0s;
  
}

.old:hover+.new {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="old">old</div>
<div class="new">new</div>
```

I think this is what you are asking. Set the transition time as large as possible to make sure they don't revert back to normal as user stays.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
    div {
        font-size: 40px;
        color: black
    }

    .new {
      display: none;
    }

    .old:hover + .new {
      display: block;
    }
```

Comment: I must replace text. No show on other lines. This is demo problem. I use on menu where OLD is text MENU and NEW is block contain lines.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `z-index` of the class `.old` and use the adjacent sibling selector to hide the `old` class and display the `.new` class.

Refer the JSFiddle below.

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/uxyz7ksq/3/)

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: black
}

.new {
  opacity: 0;
}

.old {
  z-index: 1;
}

.old:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

.old:hover+.new {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="old">Old</div>
<div class="new">New</div>
```

Comment: I can including "New" as subselect? I updated your solution (https://jsfiddle.net/uxyz7ksq/9/) After mouse New no mouseover to back Old but stay then mouse outside from all two areas.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking but I understand that after hovering "old" and the "new" text comes, it should not revert back to the "old" on mouseout. If that's the case, it can't be done with CSS alone. You would need some script to handle the task.

Comment: This is my source (https://jsfiddle.net/dgm35hs6/1/). On final page flickering menu button before show "overlay-menu". I must rebuild the menus, because when I use the next div as a wrapper, there are also individual menu items under the mask.